# Flask restplus SQL query output formatting

Tags: python, flask, sqlplus, flask-restful, flask-restplus

Using sqlplus inside python to generate SQL output. Running this via flaskplus, the formatting is lost i.e. the characters like \n,\t are not getting rendered. Tried different ways to fix this but din't help. 'print' works but 'return' doesn't work fine.

```
@api.route('/db-health-report')
class runSqlQuery(Resource):
    def get(self):
        session = Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connect_string], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        session.stdin.write(sql_command)
        queryResult, errorMessage = session.communicate()
        #print(queryResult, file=sys.stderr)
        #return queryResult.decode('string_escape')
        return queryResult
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample output?  Is the issue that `\n` is getting _ignored_ completely, or are you seeing literal `\n` in your output?

Comment: Yes, I see '\n' in the output. Example:

curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/db-health-report
"\n\n-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- SQL_ID/SQLTEXT with > 5 active sessions -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*\n\n\nno rows selected\n\n\nno rows selected\n\nRedo Generation History -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*\n\n\nDAY\t  00\t 01\t02     03     04     05     06\t   07\t  08\t 09\t10     11     12     13     14\t   15\t  16\t 17\t18     19

Comment: What is your database?  Perhaps you need to use something like `CHR(13)` if you want a literal line break.

Comment: Oracle DB
Is there a way to fix this via python code itself?

Comment: I don't know enough about your tech stack to say any more.  In Oracle, newline is `CHR(13)` (or maybe `CHAR(13)`, I can't remember which).  Maybe you could fix this in your query.